# WordPress htaccess keeps changing to chmod 444 and 777

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

After every WordPress release appears on my admin panel, my website .htaccess file becomes chmod 444 or 777 and overwrite my htaccess settings. I try to change the chmod and edit it from ftp and from the console. But It keeps returning to chmod 444 or 777. The work-around solution is that i have to update wordpress from the administration panel, then I can change the .htaccess chmod to 644 and edit it without any problem.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by renaming wp-admin to wp-admin_old and wp-includes to wp-includes_old . Then I uploaded latest and fresh folders from the official website: https://wordpress.org/. DO NOT FORGET TO DELETE 'wp-admin_old' & 'wp-includes_old'! Because they have a hidden backdoor that keeps changing your wordpress settings. That's why renaming them then deleting them is the only way to get rid of malware.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to upgrade WP is via the admin panel....
If you download the installation and do it all manually, then you need to check the umask for your user... which applies the permissions for new files.. actually there could be other reasons why the permissions change to 444, but the real solution is to upgrade via admin panel

Comment: I do upgrade through the admin panel. In fact if I do not do it I would not be able to change the htaccess chmod.

Comment: you mentioned you are doing that as a workaround.. I am confused

Comment: Yes, Everytime there is a new release of wordpress, my htaccess file changes to chmod 444 with the default htaccess settings. I can't change the chmod htaccess back to 644; thus i have to update through the admin panel then I can change the chmod to 644 and edit it back to my settings. That's the only solution I have managed to find.I want my htaccess file to remain as it is without being overwritten or modified.

Comment: how do you upgrade BEFORE you do admin panel upgrade, is what I am trying to understand. Also is the user you are upgrading with the same user that owned all the files of the current wordpress, if not, that might be the reason why you cannot chmod

Comment: it would have been very helpful if you provide examples on what exactly you do and how, so we can replicate it..

Comment: It is the same user. Whenever there is a wordpress release you can see it when you enter the admin panel right ? at that moment my htaccess changes.

Comment: your .htaccess permissions change before you actually upgrade, but login to admin, and see that a new version is available? This sounds like a Plugin issue..

Comment: Exactly!! Sorry for the confusion! I just updated my question. You think so Sir ? What do you suggest ?

Comment: What plugins do you have enabled?

Comment: I have : All in one seo, stopspammer, facebook auto publish,  bwp external links, Feed Thumbnails, iframe, permalink finder, AbsoluteRSS, Add featured image to RSS feed, Easy Flash Embed, Evermore, open graph, Subscribe Button by AddToAny

Answer (score 0):

This probably happened due to an infection, which may have changed more than the core Wordpress files. Simply updating the `wp-includes` directory may not permanently solve the problem: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191570/20963